# How to use urls in React CSS inline styling without `$`?

Tags: css, reactjs

Learning React and trying to cheat off [this codepen](https://codepen.io/JiaYuisalolicon/pen/xYjwyE?editors=0010). I do not understand 2 things.

1. What is the ... before largebox, flex, and other css classes?
    `return <div style={{...largebox, ...flex}} key={props.id}`
2. What does the $ do in the css url param? Is it jQuery? 
   `url(${props.photo})

```js
const FormCard = (props) => (
  <div>
    {
      DATA.map((props) => {
        return <div style={{...largebox, ...flex}} key={props.id}>
          <div style={{...Photo,backgroundImage: `url(${props.photo})`}}></div>
          <div>
            <Author author={props.author}/>
            <Something bio={props.bio}/>
            <AdBox adpic={props.adpic} />
            <IconBox />
          </div>
      </div>
      })
    }
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The three dots '...' are called spread operator, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
2. The `$` sign is no Jquery but is actually referencing template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Hopefully, the docs are enough as I currently can't find [the link] to [that tutorial] I remember...

Answer (score 1):

1. Spread operator:

   ```
   const styleA = { color: 'red' };
   const styleB = { background: 'blue' };

   const styleC = { ...styleA, ...styleB };

   // styleC = {color: "red", background: "blue"}
   ```
2. String Template:

   ```
   const user = 'Bob';

   const greetings = `Hello ${user}`;

   // greetings = 'Hello Bob'
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This is a perfect example. but wouldn't {{color:"red"}} still work, or no?

Comment: Only if it is a prop ex: 
<div style={{color: 'red'}} /> 
or 
<div style={{color:'red', ...moreStyles}} />
This won't work: <div style={color:'red'}

Answer (score 1):

for your first question  we call it [`Spread Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in a simple description for below line :

```
 style={{...largebox, ...flex}}
```

this is mean copy all property of largebox and flex object into a new object and assing it to style.or this line means :

```
style={{...Photo,backgroundImage:"myurl}"}
```

create a new object for me with all property of Photo object and also add a property with name `backgroundImage` to it. so if Photo is equal to `{name:'1.jpg'}` the new object is equal to

```
{name:'1.jpg',backgroundImage:"myUrl"}
```

Now for your second question, this is template literal and allow you to write variables or call functions inside a string. think we have not this so we must write it like :

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + props.photo +")"
```

so as you see it is something like concating `props.photo` and other strings.but with template literals we can wrap string with backticks and then write variable or function of javascript between `${}` like below

```
backgroundImage: `url(${props.photo})`
```

then `${props.photo}` replace with its value.

Comment: Thank you! great explanation. Reading this helped it sink in. will definitely use these templates going forward!